# Kuman 7 inch LCD screen not working

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen, lcd

I'm new to all things pi and just got a Kuman 7" 800 480 LCD screen. I tested it on my laptop first (windows 8.1) and it looked great. Plugging it into the pi, not so great. The colours are all off, only part of the screen is used and image quality is awful. I can see enough to use it but would prefer it to work properly.

I've followed the instructions from Kumantech's site [here](https://mega.nz/#F!iI9WjThL!VHRNzC44Cxlx7CjIQQJqBQ!LIdHgBja) reinstalling raspbian (not sure which version) after making the changes to the config.txt. Nothing has changed though. The screen image from the pi is still terrible. The touch screen works (sort of) but needs calibrating.

Answer (score 1):

To correct the screen size, edit the /boot/config.txt file and add the following:

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt=800 480 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried this but still the same result. I'm using NOOBs to install each time and using the config.txt editor in NOOBs.

Comment: I'd suggest not using noobs. Just flash Raspbian Stretch with Desktop direct to the sd card using Etcher. https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/